How to create an alias for the head of a branch?
My employer likes to use version numbers in their branch names.  I dislike having to remember and verify whatever the current number is.
Is there a way to "tag" or alias their branch, so I can use a branch name which does not change?
For example, they like to use:

release/env-app-44-0-1
release/env-app-44-0-2

So it changes every release.  I don't have any influence and the rest of the herd like it this way, so there is no point in telling me not to do that.
It would be nice if I could pull and push to "release/env-app", or "foobar" for that matter.
I can't actually 'git tag' because that refers to a specific commit, whereas this is constantly changing.  Unless it is possible to tag the HEAD commit of a branch?

Consider tag git-branch instead of branch

@Guildenstern when I edited the question, I preferred adding branch instead of git-branch because I feel like that the question revolves more on how to generally refer to a branch, rather than managing them via git-branch. Quoting the git-branch doc: "List, create, or delete branches". However. If you deem that the git-branch tag would be a better fit than branch, feel free to edit and improve this question.


I can't actually 'git tag' because that refers to a specific commit, whereas this is constantly changing. Unless it is possible to tag the HEAD commit of a branch?

If you were to tag the head of a branch, you would still tag a specific commit (the branch's tip). Rather than a tag, you're looking for a sort of "branch alias".
To create an "alias" that always points to the tip of your release branch, you could define a symref. This would work exactly like the HEAD symref, which always points to the tip of the referenced branch, as a symref is simply implemented as a file containing the name of the branch it refers to.
You can create a symref with the plumbing command git symbolic-ref.
git symbolic-ref refs/heads/foobar refs/heads/release/env-app-44-0-2

Like so, you could use foobar to perform any operation (checkout, rebase, etc.) as if you were working with the env-app-44-0-2 branch. Then, once the next release branch is ready, you can update the symref with the new branch.
git symbolic-ref refs/heads/foobar refs/heads/release/env-app-44-0-3


This is brilliant. How did I never stumble upon this so far? I don't know but I thank you @dani :-)

@RomainValeri glad I could help more than one person :)

This is indeed super useful when someone makes a branch named do-quick-migration-to-upgraded-framework which ends up living for months.
